# Vertically center menu within variable height header

Tags: css

I have a header that may or may not contain an image/logo and whose size is variable.

I'd like to vertically align my navigation menu within the header regardless of the size of the logo.

I've tried the ghost element trick to vertically center the nav but can't get it to work. I think this is perhaps due to the logo being floated.

Markup:

```
<header class="cf">
    <div class="brand">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.brand {
    float: right;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/R247T/

Comment: try `display:table` on the wrapper and then `vertical-align:center` on div inside - doesn't work in IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the nav to position:relative, set the ul to position:absolute and give it a top of 50%, and a margin-top of half of it's height. This will work as long as your menu has a fixed height. If you need a floating sub menu you will still be good as you can set the menu ul to have overflow:visible, but it MUST have a fixed height. If you can do that, you are golden.

```
nav {
    position:relative;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:50%;
    height:26px;
    margin-top:-13px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R247T/2/

Note, this should work on older browsers as well.

Comment: It will break if there's no image since ul is absolute the container will be empty, use min-height: @navbarheight  or padding:@navbarheight/2 on the container.

Comment: I removed the image, and it still works. This is because he is using a clearfix solution, I think. http://jsfiddle.net/R247T/6/

Comment: Correct, we're using clearfix so the header will always have a height.

Comment: Nope i'm sorry but the clearfix isn't the thing, your header got a height because it get : padding: 1em;
http://jsfiddle.net/R247T/7/
Clearfix works only for floated element not absolute positioned

Comment: You're right, I missed the padding. Double checked, and `clear:` does deal with floats rather than absolute positioning. Adding a min-height as you suggested would fix it, but the padding that is there already means it doesn't really need it. And it may never be an issue if there will always be an image. Good catch though.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention [browser support](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d), but using `transform` may work, if I understand correctly:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R247T/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd throw this alternate solution into the mix.  You can also vertically align (and horizontally for that matter), by absolute positioning the element and using `margin: auto`.

The only caveat for this approach is that you will need to specify a height and width for the links nav.

```
nav {
    margin: auto 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R247T/5/)

Comment: Your fiddle link just goes to my original fiddle.